# How to input different page layouts in same document?

Tags: environments, input, layout

I'm currently trying to adapt a template I found for a ''cook book'' and I wanted to include different page layouts to keep the document a little bit varied. I know Latex isn't the best tool for such a project and something like Canva would surely work way better. For reasons I am determined on proceding with Latex and I would like your help with one of the issues I've run to.

My general document setup is the following: I have a folder with the templates where I define the general commands and include the packages. Among other commands is the ''Style picker''

```
\newcommand{\Style}[1]{
\ifthenelse{#1=1}{\input{templates/template_s1}}{}
\ifthenelse{#1=2}{\input{templates/template_s2}}{}
\ifthenelse{#1=3}{\input{templates/template_s3}}{}
\ifthenelse{#1=4}{\input{templates/template_s4}}{}
}
```

I also have the documents outlining the templates s1 to s4, and that's where the problem lies. In the original template, you would input the \Style directly into the main document, so all the commands associated with it would be universal for the whole document. I want to be able to select a \Style for each individual recipe, but some of the command names overlap between the templates. For example, I have both of these ingredient environments, the specifics of which are irrelevant, it's just for illustrative purposes.

```
\newenvironment{ingredient}
  {\noindent\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth,height=2.5cm,clip,viewport=\@ImageDim]{\@ImagePath}}\x
  \maketitle
  
  \begin{footnotesize}
    \noindent
    \begin{tabular}{L{0.62\linewidth}L{0.33\linewidth}}
        \vspace{-0.21cm}
        \textcolor{red!60}{\textbf{{\normalsize Ingredients}}} & \\ % here is the "Ingredients" row
        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
            \vspace{0.2cm}
            }
            {\vspace{-0.2cm}
        \end{minipage}
        & \vspace{-1.8cm}Prep time: \@PrepTime \,min % here began tikzpicture
        \par \vspace{0.2cm} Cooking: \@CookingTime min -- \@CookingTempe 
        \par \vspace{0.2cm} %Type of cooking: \@TypeCooking \vspace{0.2cm} 
        \par Utensiles: \@Utensiles \\
    \end{tabular}
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \end{footnotesize}
    }
```

and

```
\newenvironment{ingredient}
    {\noindent\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand}\x
    \maketitle
    
    \begin{footnotesize}
        \noindent
        \begin{tabular}{L{0.3\linewidth}L{0.2\linewidth}c}
            \vspace{-0.21cm}
            \textcolor{red!60}{\textbf{{\normalsize Zutaten}}} & \\ % here is the "Ingredients" row
            \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
                \vspace{0.2cm}
                }
                {\vspace{-0.2cm}
            \end{minipage} 
            & \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
                \vspace{0.2cm}
                Prep-Zeit: \@PrepTime min % here began tikzpicture
                \par \vspace{0.2cm} Kochen: \@CookingTime min,     \@CookingTempe 
                \par \vspace{0.2cm}  
                \par Geräte: \@Utensiles 
            \end{minipage}
            & \begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=210pt]{\@ImagePath}
        \end{minipage} \\ 
        \end{tabular}
        \vspace{0.5cm} 
    \end{footnotesize}
    }
```

Since I am defining the environment twice, once in \Style a and once in \Style b, I get a multitude of errors and sometimes the code doesn't compile. Is there a way to define a ''parent'' environment, which picks the right style depending on the Style picker?

Comment: You can define styles inside a group (`{...}` `\bgroup ... \egroup` or `\begingroup ... \endgroup`) and most (but not necessarily all) definitions will be local to the group.

Answer (score 1):

A common idiom here isto define all the styles globally with different names so

```
\newenvironment{ingredientA}{..}{...}
..
\newenvironment{ingredientsB}{..}{...}
```

then within your style switch

```
\ifthenelse{#1=1}{\let\ingredientA\ingredient \let\endingredient\endingredientA}{}
```

which will make `\begin{ingredient}` locally use the definition `\begin{ingredientA}`

LaTeX uses this kind of construct in lots of places eg `\\`  is normally  `\@normalcr`, `tabular` it is `\@tabularcr`, in `longtable` it is `\LT@tabularcr`

Comment: Thank you. I ran into some different problems and I temporarily gave up, but I will keep your solution in mind for when I continue.